# What is the name of this connector from a fan?

Tags: connector, identification

I am EE hobbyist and I often used recycled parts in my projects. I came across this connector to a Heat Sink Fan and would like to know the name of it.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: The informal term is a "four-pin fan connecter".  Won't help you find the part in a catalog, but will help you if you're talking to the computer geeks who use most of the fans with that connector.

Comment: Over 6 years later, and this is still a helpful Q&A!. It makes me wonder though... maybe there should be a `Stack Exchange` for Connectors (esp Molex :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that it could be Molex 47054-1000.

Found it in section 4.1.5 on page 17 of this doc: http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5Crev1_2_public.pdf

Here is a Molex product page: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0470541000_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

Answer (score 19):

The three-pin version (non-PWM) is referred to by some computer technicians as a “TX3 connector”, but this is something of a misnomer (similar to the moniker “Molex connector”, referring to the once-common 4-pin ATX power connectors originally produced by AMP).

The standard 3- and 4-pin fan connectors are Molex KK series connectors. According to
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan#Connectors) the part numbers for the 4-pin version are:

- Female Housing: [47054-1000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0470541000/2405319)
- Female Contacts (obsolete): [08-50-0114](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0008500114/26475)
- Male Header: [47053-1000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0470531000/2421261)

Of course, many manufacturers produce compatible connectors, and most 0.1 inch (2.54 mm) pitch headers will work with these connectors provided they are long enough (approx 0.3 inch, or 8 mm).

Comment: You've anticipated my question with your comment re mating with 0.1" headers :)

Answer (score 2):

On sites like Aliexpress, the magic keyword appears to be KF2510 (and sometimes KF2540 for the opposite gender).

They have both "4 pin" and "3+1 pin" versions.  The "3+1 pin" variant is the one seen commonly in the PC world, which will allow both 3-pin and 4-pin plugs to mate.  The "4 pin" socket will only let other "4 pin" plugs mate, and will not accept 3-pin plugs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know very much about electronics, but I recognize this as the 4-pin connector of a fan that uses PWM to regulate the speed. It's a newer technique where previously varying the voltage was used. It will work just fine if black is connected to ground and yellow to +12V. Green is used to measure the RPM and blue regulate the speed.

Comment: Those colors are accurate for the OP's pictured connector, but there is no standard; many PWM fans also use all black wires, or red for +12V, yellow or white for the tach. signal, and blue or green for the PWM signal.